# to get list of child object from java webpage

Tags: hp-uft, uft14, uft-api

i wanted to get list of child object from java webpage ...i am new to it..please help me with the steps

i tried

```
Dim getElement
Set getElement = Description.Create
getElement("class description").value = "text box"

'I tried different class names: "OracleTextField", "JavaEdit"    
'getElement("micclass").value = "OracleTextField"
'getElement("micclass").value = "JavaEdit"

Set obj = Browser("xxxx").JavaApplet("Main").JavaInternalFrame("yyyy").ChildObjects(getElement)

total = obj.Count
```

but do not know how to call values
thanks

shree